# check a condition inside foreach and assign one of the list

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a Image Editor and I am using **ImageListView** Dll for displaying selected image, and I have a problem, in some situation I need to get the value from one list and another situation value get from another list.

I am trying like below

```
    foreach (ImageListViewItem item in ((flag == 1) ? imageListView1.Items : imageListView1.SelectedItems))
    {
        item.BeginEdit();
        using (Image img = Image.FromFile(item.FileName))
        {
            glb_namelist_arr.Add(item.FileName);
            Bitmap im=new Bitmap(item.FileName);
            glb_image_list_arr.Add(im);

        }
        item.Update();
        item.EndEdit();
    }
```

In this line I got the error :

```
((flag == 1) ? imageListView1.Items : imageListView1.SelectedItems)
```

In JavaScript I can use the `eval()` method but here what can I do?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you get *cannot implicitly convert from... error*. Yes typically they will be implemented as different collection types. Source code says that [ImageListViewSelectedItemCollection](https://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/source/browse/trunk/ImageListView/ImageListViewSelectedItemCollection.cs) and [ImageListViewItemCollection](https://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/source/browse/trunk/ImageListView/ImageListViewItemCollection.cs) implements `IList<ImageListViewItem>`.

So, you could do

```
var items = ((flag == 1) ? (IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.Items : (IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.SelectedItems);

foreach (ImageListViewItem item in items)
{
  ...
}
```

If not, provide more information about the problem. Like what is the error, what are types of  `imageListView1.Items` and `imageListView1.SelectedItems` and documentation/project link of your `ImageListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition before foreach loop

```
List<ImageListViewItem> imageListViewItemList = new List<ImageListViewItem>();

if(flag==1)
{
    imageListViewItemList = imageListView1.Items;
}
else
{
    imageListViewItemList = imageListView1.SelectedItems;
}

foreach(ImageListViewItem item in imageListViewItemList)
{

    // your code here

}
```

Comment: What is the difference here? Also I suspect `imageListView1.Items` and `imageListView1.SelectedItems` will not be of type `List<ImageListViewItem>`

Comment: It is just a way. Please use their respective data types.

Comment: What different it makes is my question. How it differs from OP's code. How does this solves the error(unknown yet) ?

Comment: They're obviously not the same types, else the code in the question wouldn't throw an error.  I don't think this helps, it's pretty much a different way of writing the same thing.

Comment: @Merbin Joe : What is the datatype of imageListView1.Items and imageListView1.SelectedItems

Comment: @captainsac it is not working, showing error, I tried already this way.

Comment: If both the datatypes are different then how can you assign it to ImageListViewItem type? Try using var as suggested by @Sriram Sakthivel only if item has a property of FileName in both those lists